# An elegant way of attaching a form helper to an Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**UPDATE**
moved to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88910/an-elegant-way-of-creating-a-helper-for-my-angular-controller)

I am looking for an elegant way of attaching a helper to my angular controller. I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614545/how-can-i-add-some-small-utility-functions-to-my-angularjs-application) and made some slight modifications to take `$scope` into account. This is what I have so far:

Here is my helper:

```
var productForm = {
  helpers: {
    setup: function($scope) {
      this.$scope = $scope;
    },
    isInvalid: function(ngModel) {
      return this.$scope.productForm[ngModel].$invalid && !this.$scope.productForm[ngModel].$pristine;
    }
  }
};
```

In my controller, I am doing the following:

```
intakeApp.controller("MageProductCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.helpers = productForm.helpers;
  $scope.helpers.setup($scope);
  ...
}
```

in my view, I am referencing the helper as such:

```
<span class="help-block" ng-show="helpers.isInvalid('designer')">can't be blank</span>
```

Any room for improvement?

Comment: Probably better suited on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)  (but you need to create a fully working example first)

Comment: thanks, i didn't know that thing existed.