# Why would you ever use the $rootScope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Ok so I was reading here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19614545/how-can-i-add-some-small-utility-functions-to-my-angularjs-application)

basically when I have this

```
MyApp = MyApp || {};

MyApp.settings = {
    isFooEnabled: false
}
```

if I use the rootscope and want to check if `isFooEnabled` I have to inject the rootScope into whatever object I want to do the check.

How does that make sense?

What is the advantage of using `$rootScope.isFooEnabled` over using straight standard javascript `MyApp.isFooEnabled`?

what is better for what?

when should I use one over the other?

Comment: The first use of $rootscope which comes to my mind is $rootscope.broadcast, which can be used for global events dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

The $rootScope is the top-most scope. An app can have only one $rootScope which will be shared among all the components of an app. Hence it acts like a global variable. All other $scopes are children of the $rootScope.

The rootScope's variable is set when the module initializes, and then each of the inherited scope's get their own copy which can be set independently.

NOTE:

> 1. When you use ng-model with $rootScope objects then AngularJS updates those objects under a specific $scope of a controller but not
>      at global level $rootScope.
> 2. The $rootScope shouldn't be used to share variables when we have things like services and factories.

Finally, Angular FAQ says this at the bottom of the page: "Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data." See from [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq).

Comment: @EdHinchliffe Why? The service's job is to not store data, it is to provide a data retrieval mechanism. For storing data Angular provides us with values and constants which are much better suited for storing and retrieving data who's only existence is inside the application.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 yes, I agree that `constant` and `value` are good choices - to be honest I read it as if the implication was to use `$rootScope` instead of a service. That said, the difference between a `constant` and a `factory` is so subtle that I rarely bother with constants.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe There is a major difference in constant and factory. A factory is like a C# controller where the constant is like a C# model. One is designed to do and the other is designed to hold.

Comment: @tuckerjt07 but we're not using c#. In angular the difference is minor: a `factory` accepts a function that is run (once) to return a result, and the `constant` simply accepts the result directly. There are exceptions (when `.config` blocks are involved), but in most cases the tangible difference is tiny.

Comment: @EdHinchliffe In C# the difference is minor, both are classes and capable of doing the other's work. What you are attempting to justify is a bad design pattern, as evidenced by the framework's creator's statement. A factory has more overhead associated with it than a constant as well due to how they are created by the framework. Inoptimal decisions no matter how minor become major problems when enough are added together.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would argue that you *shouldn't* use `$rootScope` in this case, you should create a separate service (or factory) that stores your settings, however, the usage and reasons are the same.

For simply storing values, the primary reason is consistency. Modules and dependency injection are a big part of angular to ensure you write testable code, and these all use dependency injection so that unit tests can be written easily (dependencies can be mocked). Whilst there are not many obvious gains from injecting a simple object, it's consistent with the way more complex code is accessed, and there is a lot to be said for that. On a similar note, if you were to upgrade your settings object to fetch data from the server (e.g. for environment specific settings), you might want to start unit testing that functionality, which you can't really do properly without modularising it.

There is also the (frankly weak) namespacing argument - what if another library you import uses `window.MyApp`?

**TL;DR:** It's a strongly recommended best-practice. It might seem a bit clunky now, but you'll benefit from doing it in the long run.

Comment: ever heard of `YAGNI`. `You ain't gonna need it`. Upgrade your setting to fetch data from server? no it won't. I mean if i want to fetch something from the server, I can do it in the `run` und set the config accordingly. Right? "A service" : Now I have to inject a bloody service in all my controllers that want to see if something of my global config is enabled?

Comment: Yep - it's a choice. If you want to use a global variable there's nothing stopping you for sure. I personally don't mind injecting the service, I think it keeps it all neat, and what's more, my settings *do* sometimes fetch data from the server :)